# Select routing-instance in Paramiko

Tags: python, networking, routes, paramiko

I'm looking for example Paramiko to support or connected via routing instance option.

So, all traffic will go via specified routing instance instead of default routing instance. In router, we do have two routing table (default routing table and xyz routing table). I want to connect the router via xyz routing table instead of default routing table via Paramiko.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to select network interface that Paramiko should use?

Comment: In router, we do have two routing table (default routing table  and xyz routing table). I want to connect the router via xyz routing table instead of default routing table via paramiko. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a networking expert, but I do not think you can select a routing table on a client side.

I believe that your router must create two networks (or it already does), each with a different routing table. Your machine need to connect to both of them, having a different IP address on each. You can then select from which IP address you connect, effectively choosing the network and routing table to connect through.

But this is not supported in Paramiko:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/206

Though it seems that a small change to Paramiko code will allow it.